# REST API for data processing and method chaining

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

I apologize in advance if the quality of the question is bad. I am still beginning to learn the concepts of REST API. I am trying to implement a scalable REST API for data processing. Here is what I could think of so far.

Consider some numerical data that can be retrieved using a `GET` call:

```
GET http://my.api/data/123/
```

Users can apply a sequence of arithmetic operations such as `add` and `multiply`. A non-RESTful way to do that is:

```
GET http://my.api/data/123?add=10&multiply=5
```

**Assupmtions:**

- The original data in the DB is not changed. Only an altered version of it is returned to the user.
- The data is large in size (say a large multi-dimensional array), so we can't afford to return the whole data with every opertation call. Instead, we want to apply operations as a batch and return the final modified data in the end.

There are 2 RESTful ways I am currently conisdering:

### 1. Model arithmetic operations as subresources of data.

If we consider `add` and `multiply` as subresources of data [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877968/call-a-server-side-method-on-a-resource-in-a-restful-way). In this case, we can use:

```
GET http://my.api/data/123/add/10/
```

which would be safe and idempotent, given that the original data is never changed. However, we need to chain multiple operations. Can we do that?

```
GET http://my.api/data/123/add/10/multiply/5/
```

Where `multiply` is creating a subresource of `add/10/` which itself is a subresource of `data/123`

**Pros:**

- Statelessness: The sever doesn't keep any information about the modified data.
- Easy access to modified data: It is just a simple GET call.

**Cons:**

- Chaining: I don't know if it can be easily implemented.
- Long URIs: with each operation applied, the URI gets longer and longer.

### 2. Create an *editable* data object:

In this case, a user creates an editable version of the original data:

```
POST http://my.api/data/123/
```

will return

```
201 Created
Location: http://my.api/data/123/edit/{uniqueid}
```

Users can then `PATCH` this editable data

```
PATCH http://my.api/data/123/edit/{uniqueid}
{add:10, multiply:5}
```

And finally, `GET` the edited data

```
GET http://my.api/data/123/edit/{uniqueid}
```

**Pros:**

- Clean URIs.

**Cons:**

- The server has to save the state of edited data.
- Editing is no long idempotent.
- Getting edited data requires users to make at least 3 calls.

Is there a cleaner, more semantic way to implement data processing RESTfully?

## Edit:

If you are wondering what is the real world problem behind this, I am dealing with digital signal processing.

As a simple example, you can think of applying visual filters to images. Following [this example](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/), a RESTful web service can do:

```
GET http://my.api/image/123/blur/5px/rotate/90deg/?size=small&format=png
```

Comment: Why is "GET http://my.api/data/123?add=10&multiply=5" non-RESTful?? This assumes no state

Comment: Well, it depends on how you interpret it. I see that `add` and `multiply` modify the resource, rather that ***scoop*** it. I think query string should be reserved for scooping as in `GET http://my.api/data/123/add/10/?subset_from=0&subset_to=10` for example.

Comment: @ahmohamed, it this a real problem?

Comment: @Opal Of course. My application involves signal processing. I have edited the question to demonstrate that.

Comment: Why you don't want/can't keep the modified data?

Comment: I already wrote it in the *Cons* of the second method. Basically, I lose the statelessness and scalability. If 100 people accessed the data, I get 100 copies saved.

Comment: have you considered this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8275397/3219121 ?

Comment: @matagus Thanks a lot for the link. It is indeed a very good discussion of the first method (operations as subresources). However, it doesn't discuss chaining (applying operations after one another).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things worth reviewing in your question.

**REST based API’s are resource based**

So looking at your first example, trying to chain transformation properties into the URL path following a resource identifier..

`GET http://my.api/data/123/add/10/multiply/5/`

..does not fit well (as well as being complicated to implement dynamically, as you already guessed)

**Statelessness**

The idea of statelessness in REST is built around a single HTTP call containing enough information to process the request and provide a result without going back to the client for more information. Storing the result of an HTTP call on the server is not state, it’s cache.

---

***Now, given that a REST based API is probably not the best fit for your usage, if you do still want to use it here are your options:***

**1.    Use the Querystring with a common URL operation**

You could use the Querystring but simplify the resource path to accept all transformations upon a single URI. Given your examples and reluctance to store transformed results this is probably your best option.

```
GET http://my.api/data/123/transform?add=10&multiply=5
```

**2.    Use POST non-RESTfully**

You could use POST requests, and leverage the HTTP body to send in the transformation parameters. This will ensure that you don’t ever run out of space on the query string if you ever decide to do a *lot* of processing and it will also keep your communication tidier. This isn’t considered RESTful if the POST returns the image data.

**3.    Use POST RESTfully**

Finally, if you decide that you do want to cache things, your POST can in fact store the transformed object (note that REST doesn’t dictate how this is stored, in memory or DB etc.) which can be re-fetched by Id using a GET.

***Option A***

> POSTing to the URI creates a subordinate resource.

```
POST http://my.api/data/123
{add:10, multiply:5}
```

returns

```
201 Created
Location: http://my.api/data/123/edit/{uniqueid}
```

then GET the edited data

```
GET http://my.api/data/123/edit/{uniqueid}
```

***Option B***

> Remove the resource identifier from the URL to make it clear that you're creating a new item, not changing the existing one. The resulting URL is also at the same level as the original one since it's assumed it's the same type of result.

```
POST http://my.api/data
{original: 123, add:10, multiply:5}
```

returns

```
201 Created
Location: http://my.api/data/{uniqueid}
```

then GET the edited data

```
GET http://my.api/data/{uniqueid}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am currently leaning towards RESTful POST  Option A `http://my.api/data/123/edit/{uniqueid}`, since it is more semantic in indicating that the response is an **edited** copy of the data. The data can be stored to the server in a short-lived cache for scalability

Comment: Since the the purpose of the question was to stir discussion on the subject, I will accept you answer because you discussed several options.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways this can be done.  In the end it should be clean, regardless of what label you want to give it (REST non-REST).  REST is not a protocol with an RFC, so don't worry too much about whteher you pass information as URL paths or URL params.  The underlying webservice should be able to get you the data regarless of how it is passed.  For example Java Jersey will give you your params no matter if they are param or URL path, its just an annotation difference.

Going back to your specific problem I think that the resource in this REST type call is not so much the data that is being used to do the numerical operations on but the actual response.  In that case, a POST where the data ID and the operations are fields might suffice.

`POST http://my.api/operations/`

```
{
    "dataId": "123",
    "operations": [
        {
            "type": "add",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "type": "multiply",
            "value": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

The response would have to point to the location of where the result can be retrieved, as you have pointed out.  The result, referenced by the location (and ID) in the response, is essentially an immutable object.  So that is in fact the resource being created by the POST, not the data used to calculate that result.  Its just a different way of viewing it.

EDIT:  In response to your comment about not wanting to store the outcome of the operations, then you can use a callback to transmit the results of the operation to the caller.  You can easily add the a field in the JSON input for the host or URL of the callback.  If the callback URL is present, then you can POST to that URL with the results of the operation.

```
{
    "dataId": "123",
    "operations": [
        {
            "type": "add",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "type": "multiply",
            "value": 5
        }
    ],
    "callBack": "<HOST or URL>"
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the way I'd go.  In this way, you could do `POST http://my.api/image/123/filters {"blur":"5px", "rotate":"90deg", "size":"small", "format":"png"}` and have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yours is definately one way to go (And I believe there's no one correct answer to the question). But I think that this way not scalable also, since it creates multiple copies of the data with each time.

Comment: Was the data intended to be altered?  I thought that the operation was intended to not alter the original data and that client just wants the output of the operation.

Comment: I think your understanding is correct. The original data resource is not altered. I mean by 'creating copies' that a new resource (with the altered data) is created with each request. Since the data size (and hence the altered data also) is big, this presents a scalability issue.

Comment: 3 points to consider.  First, whether you use POST, GET, JSON, or params, this should not affect the underlying implementation.  If the implementation creates extra objects that need to be kept, then change it.  Second point is your requirement `The data is large in size (say a large multi-dimensional array), so we can't afford to return the whole data with every opertation call. Instead, we want to apply operations as a batch and return the final modified data in the end.`.  Third point, if you do not want to store the object after it is calculated, then you can use a call back.

Answer (score 2):

*Please don't view this as me answering my own question, but rather as a constribution to the discussion.*

I have given a lot of thought into this. The main problem with the currently suggested architectures is scalability, since the server creates copies of data each time it is operated on.

The only way to avoid this is to model `operations` and `data` separately. So, similar to Jose's answer, we create a resource:

```
POST http://my.api/operations/
{add:10, multiply:5}
```

Note here, I didn't specify the data at all. The created resource represents a series of operations only. The `POST` returns:

```
201 Created
Location: http://my.api/operations/{uniqueid}
```

The next step is to **apply** the `operations` on the data:

```
GET http://my.api/data/123/operations/{uniqueid}
```

This seprate modeling approach have several advantages:

1. Data is not replicated each time applies a different set of operations.
2. Users create only `operations` resources, and since their size is tiny, we don't have to worry about scalability.
3. Users *create* a new resource only when they need a *new* set of operations.Going to the image example: if I am designing a greyscale website, and I want all images to be converted to greyscale, I can do

   ```
   POST http://my.api/operations/
   {greyscale: "50%"}
   ```

   And then *apply* this operation on all my images by:

   ```
   GET http://my.api/image/{image_id}/operations/{geyscale_id}
   ```

   As long as I don't want to change the operation set, I can use `GET` only.
4. Common operations can be created and stored on the server, so users don't have to create them. For example:

   ```
   GET http://my.api/image/{image_id}/operations/flip
   ```

   Where `operations/flip` is already an available operation set.
5. Easily, applying the same set of operations to different data, and vice versa.

   ```
   GET http://my.api/data/{id1},{id2}/operations/{some_operation}
   ```

   Enables you to compare two datasets that are processed similarly. Alternatively:

   ```
   GET http://my.api/data/{id1}/operations/{some_operation},{another_operation}
   ```

   Allows you to see how different processing procedures affects the result.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to describe your math function using the URI or request body. We have a more or less standard language to describe math, so you could use some kind of template.

```
GET http://my.api/data/123?transform="5*(data+10)"
POST http://my.api/data/123 {"transform": "5*({data}+10)"}
```

You need a code on client side, which can build these kind of templates and another code in the server side, which can verify, parse, etc... the templates built by the client.

Comment: The math operations here are just an example for data processing. I don't think we have a standard language for signal (or image) processing in the same way you described.